# Errors while building the android platfom with IONIC

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

don't know why when I sart a Ionic project and try building the platform running the command:

```
ionic build android
```

I get this kind of error. Please see link:

http://gyazo.com/95b0bc14bb155b49124bf09b07c98f9c

Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: did you manage to solve your problem in the end?

Comment: Unforrtunately no...when i run the command I still get errors....see screenshot http://gyazo.com/ee9543cc7dbedde67b399348878efc7f

Answer (score 1):

This is the main error: `Please install Android target: "android-22"`.

Please follow the [official tutorial](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) on how to set up your Android dev tools.

Short answer: You need to install Android 22 from your Android SDK Manager:
[image]